# Trim top and bottom rows from CSV UNIX SH

Tags: csv, unix, tail, unix-head

I need to trim the top 5 rows and the last row of my `csv` using a Unix 
 command that I can run in a `shell script`.

I currently have `head -n -1 file.csv | tail -n +6 file.csv > newfile.csv` this outputs a new csv starting from row 6 which is what I need however the first part of the command fails as `illegal line count -- -1`

Comment: Try `tail -n +6 file.csv | head -n -1...`

Answer (score 0):

I first done `tail -n +6 file.csv` to remove the first 5 rows.

Then to remove the last row of the `csv` i had to flip the `csv` so the last row was at the top I done this by using the `tail -r` command.

I then used the same command from the start to remove the now first row `tail -n +2` and finally flipped the `csv` back using the `tail -r` command.

`tail -n +11 input.csv | tail -r | tail -n +2  | tail -r > output.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to delete the last line (and the first five), you can use `sed` far more simply:

```
sed -e '1,5d; $d' file.csv
```

Literally: delete lines 1 through 5; delete the last line.

If you needed to delete more than one line at the end, this would not work; `sed` doesn't generally support relative motions like `$-4`.  In that case, I'd probably use `ed` or `ex`:

```
{ echo '1,5d'; echo '$-4,$d'; echo 'w'; echo 'q'; } | ed file.csv
```

Delete lines 1,5; delete from four lines before the last to the last (removing 5 lines at the end); write the file; quit (where the quit is optional but the write isn't).